# Call to undefined method Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

i have problems

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2258: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::add()

Controller

```
public function Cart(Request $request, $id){

            $products_buy = Products::find($id);

            Carts::add(array('id'=>$id,'name'=>$products_buy->name_product,
                             'qty'=>1,'price'=>$products_buy->price,
                             'options'=>array('img'=>$products_buy->picture)));

            $content= Carts::content();
            return View('pay.cart')->with(
                "cart",$content
            );      
        }
```

Comment: should you use Carts::create instead of Carts::add?

Comment: @Brett: thanks you, it's worked ^^

Comment: brett, i was writing the answer, you do it mate

Comment: @Brett, @Achraf Khouadja:  i have a question, i meet error after change add-> create 
`MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 449:
id` and `at Model->fill(array('id' => '4', 'name' => 'Cup', 'qty' => '1', 'price' => '1000', 'options' => array('img' => 'product-harvest-moon-cup-45deg-4x3.jpg')))`

Comment: You probably need to change the field to product_id and not have it just as id as laravel uses that as the Primary Key not a Foreign Key

Answer (score 2):

In laravel 5.2 to correctly create an entry use

```
Model::create
```

not

```
Model::add
```

Please note this adds it to the database straight away.

If you don't want to add straight away use

```
$flight = new Flight;
$flight->fill($valuesArray);
$flight->save();
```

only call save when ready to commit to DB

If you get a Mass Assignment error. You need to ensure all the values in the array you pass to create or fill are set in the model in the $fillables variable. If it is not in the fillable it can't be assigned in the fill or create method and you have to manually do it. $model->value_not_in_fillable = 1;

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

Comment: @BiHíp if it's the correct answer please accept it as the answer